# Higher kinded types as type variables in Haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types, type-variables

I have a class:

```
import Linear

class Coordinate c where
    rotate :: Num a => Quaternion a -> c a -> c a
    translate :: Num a => V3 a -> c a -> c a
```

, for which I have defined the instances

```
instance Coordinate V3 where
    rotate _ = id
    translate p = (p+)

instance Coordinate Quaternion where
    rotate o = (o*)
    translate _ = id
```

Now I want to define an instance for a pair of members of the class.

```
instance (Coordinate a, Coordinate b) => Coordinate (a, b) where
    rotate o (a, b) = (rotate o a, rotate o b)
    translate p (a, b) = (translate p a, translate p b)
```

The problem is that this does not work, since the compiler expects an argument for `a` and `b`. However adding a type-constraint like

```
instance (Coordinate a, Coordinate b, Num c) => Coordinate (a c, b c) where
    move p (a, b) = (move p a, move p b)
    translate p (a, b) = (translate p a, translate p b)
```

It does not work either, since this results in an expression with the kind `*` rather than  `* -> *`. I can see how both of the above are incorrect, but I am unsure of how to solve this. I suppose there should be some form of constraint that keeps the `Num` types for both `a`and `b` the same, but I don't know what that would look like syntactically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot make an instance of this `Coordinate` class for the built-in pair type. You need to change one of them.

- The `Coordinate` class can be changed to take a normal `Type` as argument:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}

  import Data.Kind (Type)

  class Num (Component c) => Coordinate c where
      type Component c :: Type -- every Coordinate type has a Component type
      rotate :: Quaternion (Component c) -> c -> c
      translate :: V3 (Component c) -> c -> c
  ```

  E.g the `V3` instance will now look like

  ```
  instance Num a => Coordinate (V3 a) where
      type Component (V3 a) = a
      rotate _ = id
      translate = (+)
  ```

  And the pair instance will use an equality constraint, which is the thing you were looking for

  ```
  instance (Coordinate a, Coordinate b, Component a ~ Component b) => Coordinate (a, b) where
      type Component (a, b) = Component a -- or = Component b
      rotate p (l, r) = (rotate p l, rotate p r)
      translate p (l, r) = (translate p l, translate p r)
  ```
- Instead of pairs, use [`Product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html#t:Product):

  ```
  import Data.Functor.Product

  instance (Coordinate a, Coordinate b) => Coordinate (Product a b) where
      rotate p (Pair l r) = Pair (rotate p l) (rotate p r)
      translate p (Pair l r) = Pair (translate p l) (translate p r)
  ```